# Decoding an encoded text file - Python

Tags: python, decode

So suppose I have wrote a method that has encoded a text file into some gibberish that looks like

`úÎúÞ<81>i<82>ran<81><83>there<81><84>with<85>carol<86>we<81><87>did`

I have 0 sense on how to go about putting back into a normal text file that says 
`i ran there with carol we did`

the characters at the beginning are just magic numbers but I just want to check the magic numbers and take the words back out into a file ignoring the numbers.

Comment: Can you split on a regular expression that matches <\d>?  Then you can get your contents as a List that can be iterated through to re-create the string.  And if the "magic numbers" are always at the beginning, they will be at index 0.

Comment: Magic numbers? How do you check them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.split` with the right pattern will do it:

```
import re
s='úÎúÞ<81>i<82>ran<81><83>there<81><84>with<85>carol<86>we<81><87>did'
L = re.split(r'<[\d<>]+>',s)
print(L)
print(' '.join(L[1:]))
```

Output:

```
['úÎúÞ', 'i', 'ran', 'there', 'with', 'carol', 'we', 'did']
i ran there with carol we did
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re` extracting the words between the `><`:

```
s = "úÎúÞ<81>i<82>ran<81><83>there<81><84>with<85>carol<86>we<81><87>did"

import re
r = re.compile(">(.*?)<|>(.*)")
print(r.findall(s))
```

If the last word is not in wrapped in >< use:

```
print(" ".join(("".join(x) for x in r.findall(s))))
```